# Control routerLink inside component's template

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-directive, angular-components

I have a component encapsulating a mat-table:

my.component.ts:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my',
  templateUrl: './my.component.html',
  styles: ['.mat-cell { padding: 5px }']
})
export class MyComponent {
}
```

my.component.html:

```html
<table mat-table [dataSource]="[{a: 'abc', b: 'def'}, {a: 'def', b: 'ghi'}]" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="a">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>a</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.a}}</td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="b">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>b</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.b}}</td>
  </ng-container>
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="['a','b']"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['a','b']" [routerLink]="'/test/' + row.a"></tr>
</table>
```

I want to be able to control the "routerLink" in the last line when using this component.
The problem is that it needs to use data from current row so it must have access to "row" variable from the templated mat-row.

The usage could look something like this:

```js
<my *myRow="let row" [rowLink]="'/test/' + row.a"></my>
```

or

```js
<my let-row [rowLink]="'/test/' + row.a"></my>
```

or

```js
<my>
    <my-row *myRow="let row" [routerLink]="'/test/' + row.a"></my-row>
</my>
```

I found here https://medium.com/javascript-everyday/reusable-components-with-configurable-templates-in-angular-3c55741c97f3 how to make template for a row and pass a variable to it but I need to pass a variable from a template like this to template which is one level higher.

What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: so did you mean you want to control the `routerLink` on the last control and that's it?

Comment: yes, I know how to do it by passing a function into the component but I would like to avoid this